# How to run a Batch file silently?

Tags: windows-registry

Hi i'm trying to run the following Batch file silently

> regedit.exe /S Box.reg
>
> net use I: \dav.box.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\dav /user:username password

However i was prompted on running this.

Is changing UAC control to never notify is the only solution?

Comment: Perhaps you could use the [runas](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) command to run the batch file (or within it).